# s3fs.put into empty and non-empty S3 folder

Tags: python, amazon-s3, python-s3fs

I am copying folder to `S3` with `s3fs.put(..., recursive=True)` and I experience weird behavior. The code is:

```
import s3fs    

source_path = 'foo/bar'                # there are some <files and subfolders> inside
target_path = 'S3://my_bucket/baz'

s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False)
s3.put(source_path, target_path, recursive=True)
```

First time I run the command (files and S3 "folders" are created), results end up like this:

```
S3://my_bucket/baz/<files and subfolders>
```

Second time I run the command, the result looks like this

```
S3://my_bucket/baz/bar/<files and subfolders>
```

I can probably check existence of the "folders" before, but that does not solve the problem that I do not want to see `bar` in the resulting tree structure. I tried to append `'/'` to `target_path` in line with the documentation, but it did not have any effect. Is there a way to force `s3fs` behave same way regardless of existing data in S3?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is unfortunatelly, the functionality of `shutil.copy_tree(src, dst, dirs_exist_ok=True)` is missing here for `s3fs.put()`.

But the working solution for this is to put a trailing slash on the source path:

```
import s3fs  
import os  

source_path = 'foo/bar'                # there are some <files and subfolders> inside
target_path = 'S3://my_bucket/baz'

s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False)
s3.put(os.path.join(source_path, ""), target_path, recursive=True)
```

Tested it on my s3 deployment (mind the trailing slash in the second test):

```
>>> s3.put("~/some_dir_with_subdirs", "s3://my_bucket/target_dir")
>>> s3.ls("s3://my_bucket/target_dir")
['dir_1', 'file_1', 'file_2', 'file_3', 'file_4', 'file_5', 'dir_2']
>>> s3.put("~/some_dir_with_subdirs", "s3://my_bucket/target_dir")
>>> s3.ls("s3://my_bucket/target_dir")
['dir_1', 'target_dir', 'file_1', 'file_2', 'file_3', 'file_4', 'file_5', 'dir_2']

>>> s3.put("~/some_dir_with_subdirs/", "s3://my_bucket/target_dir")
>>> s3.ls("s3://my_bucket/target_dir")
['dir_1', 'file_1', 'file_2', 'file_3', 'file_4', 'file_5', 'dir_2']
>>> s3.put("~/some_dir_with_subdirs/", "s3://my_bucket/target_dir")
>>> s3.ls("s3://my_bucket/target_dir")
['dir_1', 'file_1', 'file_2', 'file_3', 'file_4', 'file_5', 'dir_2']
```